# How to get the GWT base URL or Module Name from the GWT server scope?

Tags: gwt

I know you can get the GWT module name client side using `GWT.getModuleName()` or `getHostPageBaseURL()`, but is it possible to access it from the server?

What I'm after is the base URL of the deployed application.  For example, if the GWT app is deployed as `http://foo.com/deploy1/MyModule/` what I want to know is that the request came from the base URL of `http://foo.com/deploy1/`

Simply getting the URI from the HTTP request will give me the full module path, when I really want the base (it will be deployed under different sub-paths at the same domain)

Comment: To clarify, I can get the URI from the `HttpServletRequest`, but that gives me `http://foo.com/deploy1/MyModule/`.  I'm trying to avoid hard-coding the module name `MyModule` or duplicating it in a properties file.  It's defined in by GWT module xml file, but I'd rather not have the burden of keeping that in sync with some other file(s) source code or otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) will give you the `/deploy1` path.

If you need the full URL, you can easily reconstruct it from the other `HttpServletRequest` properties, or you can start with `getRequestURL` and tweak the result to replace the *path* part.

Comment: I'm not sure how I overlooked that method, but that seems to do the trick.  Sometimes the simplest answer is the best!

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand the relationship between server and client in GWT.

So, you are looking at the usual Greetings GWT RPC stub and you see the client, server, shared folders (and you could add the public folder to place html, jsp or other files directly accessible thro the module's path).

What you probably do not realise is that the server-side responder to a client's RPC request need not be satisfied by a class within the module. Within the module you would have the RPC request definition interface where you define the server-side responder's path @RemoteServiceRelativePath("/hello").

To satisfy the RPC request thro the path "/hello", you do not need to code your servlet inside any module's "server" folder. You could even have

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("/hello.jsp")
```

or

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("/hello.php")
```

In fact, I have a login JSP which accepts RPC request from a few modules and it has to find out which module is emitting the request.

Or you could be using RequestBuilder or placing a JSON javascript-include request.

With that in mind, how would a RPC server-side responder be constrained to be defined by any module, regardless that it is placed inside the folder of a particular module? You simply have to have the client inform the server-side responder what module the client belongs to. Using a Map or HashMap as the datatype for RpC transmission would be very helpful. In case you are using REquestFactory, the identification of an entity would be able to tell your server what the module is through the entity object namespace.

http://h2g2java.blessedgeek.com/2009/08/gwt-rpc.html

Comment: +1 for the excellent explanation, but you didn't really provide an answer to the problem of retrieving the base URL as @ThomasBroyer does.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the `Referer` http header: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

Comment: I tried to clarify the question.  I can get the URI, but the problem is in getting the URI _without_ the GWT module name (or getting the module name at runtime to trim).  wouldn't  `Referer` give me the full subpath?

Answer (score 1):

2 years late, but someone else may have the same question.

Anyway, you can get the that exact data you want by using `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()`.

Comment: According to the docs, this should also be possible on server-side using ``RemoteServiceServlet.getRequestModuleBasePath()``.